# ionic 2 new project error spawned command 'npminstall'

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

Error in prompt:

```
C:\Users\Rafael\Documents\pronunciation 90475 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
90476 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" 
"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" 90477 error node v4.6.0 90478 error npm v2.15.9 90479 
error code EPEERINVALID 90480 error peerinvalid The package rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 
does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements! 90480 error 
peerinvalid Peer @angular/core@2.2.1 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 90481 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Im running node 4.6 cordova 4.5 e ionic 2.2.1

Running de cmd as Admin and the command is:

```
ionic start --v2 pronunciation sidemenu
```

If someone can help me, please

Comment: Uninstall nodejs and install it again.

Comment: Please paste the code/error here instead of link to image that way we would be able to help better.

Comment: well @Jeet here we go with the last part of the 'npm-debug' file.
90474 verbose cwd C:\Users\Rafael\Documents\pronunciation
90475 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
90476 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
90477 error node v4.6.0
90478 error npm  v2.15.9
90479 error code EPEERINVALID
90480 error peerinvalid The package rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
90480 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/core@2.2.1 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
90481 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: @Jeet if you want the entire file, i can edit my first post